# Como separar a camada DAO dos dados inserindos pelo usuário?

Tags: java

Estou tentando tirar essa camada DAO e colocar em outra classe para receber os dados digitados pelo usuário. Alguém poderia dar uma mão?

Ou seja, esse pedaço de código teria que receber os dados em outra classe, os dados da classe DadosUsuario.

```
SocioDAO dao = new SocioDAO();
try {
    dao.salvarSocio(cadastrarUser);
    System.out.println("USUÁRIO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("ERRO AO CADASTRAR USUÁRIO.");
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

```
public class DadosUsuario {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void cadastrarUsuario() throws NomeUsuarioNaoInformado{
        Socio cadastrarUser = new Socio();

        System.out.println("Informe um nome: ");
        cadastrarUser.setNome(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Informe um telefone: ");
        cadastrarUser.setTelefone(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o DDD: ");
        cadastrarUser.setDdd(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o email: ");
        cadastrarUser.setEmail(scan.next());

        System.out.println("Informe o cpf: ");
        cadastrarUser.setCpf(scan.next());

        SocioDAO dao = new SocioDAO();
        try {
            dao.salvarSocio(cadastrarUser);
            System.out.println("USUÁRIO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERRO AO CADASTRAR USUÁRIO.");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Separar que você diz, seria... MVC?

Comment: Sim... Isso mesmo... Só que esta foda para fazer isso...

Comment: Uma via fácil de fazer este tipo de divisão é utilizar um framework que irá resolver boa parte da arquitetura. O framework Demoiselle inclusive fornece uma ferramenta para geração de boa parte do CRUD: http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/tools/nimble/1.2.0/html/